# How do I find the number of integer solutions ($x,y$) that satisfy the equation $y = 3x^2 + 7xy + 4y^2$?

Tags: quadratics, integers

I'm looking for the **number** of integer solutions for this equation. This problem is from a $7$th grade math contest where you had a few minutes to answer it, but the only way to solve it I found was to find all the solutions by solving second degree equations which takes significantly more than that. Is there any way to solve this problem that, perhaps, would be easier/would get closer to that time limit? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noting that the coefficient of the middle term is the sum of the other coefficients, so there is a factor $x+y$, we find the factorisation $y=(x+y)(3x+4y)$

Set $x+y=X$ and we have $y=X(3X+y)$ and $y=\cfrac {3X^2}{1-X}$

($X=1$ is easily eliminated, so we are not dividing by zero)

Now $X$ and $1-X$ can have no [non-trivial] factor in common, so $1-X$ must be a factor of $3$ hence $(1-X)\in \{-3, -1, 1, 3\}$

Clearly each of these possibilities does provide a solution, since the steps are reversible.

Comment: Notice how the substitution was used to obtain an equation linear in $y$. That's a trick worth remembering.

Comment: I thought the factoring could be used in some way. Good. Also, https://metro.co.uk/2018/07/07/ian-wrights-priceless-reaction-dele-alli-scores-englands-second-goal-sweden-7691115/

Comment: To make use of this factorisation directly, translate the intersection of the asymptotes to the origin so the equation becomes $(x+y)(3x+4y)=-3$. Solving  $\langle x+y-1,3x+4y+3\rangle$, $\langle x+y+1,3x+4y-3\rangle$, $\langle x+y-3,3x+4y+1\rangle$, $\langle x+y+3,3x+4y-1\rangle$ we get $(7,-6),(-7,6),(13,-10),(-13,10)$ which translates back to $(0,0),(14,-12),(20,-16),(-6,4).$

Comment: Or even more directly from the asymptotes: $(x+y-1)(3x+4y+3)=-3$ rearranges to the given equation.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Of course that is the way to go to formalise the solution. I wanted to explain this in a way that a 7th grade student might be able to spot from scratch. Also it is not so clear that each choice for the factors gives an integer solution.

Comment: Point taken, that the determinants involved will be $\pm 1$ is not something to rely on in context.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I do think that your comments are pertinent and helpful, though. A good question of this kind can lead an intelligent student to explore interesting ideas - isn't that how mathematicians are made? And what you have written does give some indication of what to explore.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBennet Also, this may seem like a silly question, and I know it's very easy to figure out, but how did you come to the conclusion that 1-X and X have no common factors?

Comment: @Wiirexu Suppose $X=da$ and $1-X=db$ so there is a common factor $d$. Add the two together and you get $1=da+db$ so any common factor of the two is a factor of $1$. More generally it is often useful to know that any common factor of two integers is also a factor of their sum and of their difference. So I used this as a fact that I knew rather than working it out.

Answer (score 4):

Say $(x,y)$ is a pair of integers satisfying $y = 3x^2 + 7xy + 4y^2$. We can rewrite this as $$4y^2 + (7x-1)y + 3x^2 = 0$$ and solving for $y$ with the quadratic formula yields $$y = \frac{1-7x \pm \sqrt{(7x-1)^2 - 48x^2}}{8} = \frac{1-7x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 14x + 1}}{8}$$ For this to be an integer, we require $x^2 - 14x + 1$ to be a perfect square, call it $m^2$. Then $$(x-7-m)(x-7+m) = (x-7)^2 - m^2 = 48$$ Since both factors on the left hand side are integers, this has a finite number of integer solutions coming from factorizations of $48$. This readily yields all possible values of $x$ when combined with the condition that $y$ must itself be an integer.

Comment: Very nice your answer. Why $\ldots=48$?

Comment: @Sebastiano (x-7)^2 - m^2 = x^2 - 14x + 49 - m^2 = x^2 -14x + 1 - m^2 + 48 = m^2 - m^2 + 48 = 48

Comment: @Wiirexu I have now undestood. You have used the hypothesis $x^2 - 14x + 1=m^2$. Ok! Thank you very much.